# How to configure Google OAuth with client ID and secret from environment variables?

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod

I'd like my application's Client ID and Secret ID to NOT be part of my source code. Therefore, if I read these settings from environment variables during runtime they will always be wrapped in IO. This leads to a problem, because then they will fail to compose:

```
authPlugins :: master -> [AuthPlugin master]
authGoogleEmail :: YesodAuth m => Text -> Text -> AuthPlugin m
getEnv :: String -> IO String
```

Another way to pose this question is: how to read `clientId` and `clientSecret` from the environment in the first example code given at http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Not tested, but this should work:</strike> Full example: http://lpaste.net/167997

1. Add fields to your App record for the client id and secret:

   ```
   data App = App { ...
                  , gmailClientId :: Text
                  , gmailClientSecret :: Text
                  }
   ```
2. Modify the authPlugins method to look up the client id and secret values from the App record:

   ```
   instance YesodAuth App where
     ...
     authPlugins app = [ ...
                       , authGoogleEmail (gmailClientId app)  (gmailClientSecret app)
                       ]
   ```
3. Initialize the App record in `main` before calling `warp`:

   ```
   main = do
     clientId <- getEnv "CLIENT_ID"
     clientSecret <- getEnv "CLIENT_SECRET"
     ...
     let app = App { ..., gmailClientId = clientId, gmailClientSecret = clientSecret }
     warp 3000 app
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't realize one could use the `App` record type for stuff like this.